# Using M.2 drives on a PCIe X16 adapter card

Tags: windows, ssd, pci-express

I purchased four M.2 NVME Gen 4 4Tb SSDs and a MPG Z690 Carbon WIFI motherboard. I want to do everything possible to produce the fastest read/write speeds from the individual drives.

To be clear, I do not want a RAID array, but four separate 4Tb drives. In reading several posts here, it appears this is a common practice.

This board has 5 M.2 slots, with one a Gen 3, the others are Gen 4. So, this is the trouble spot for me. The first M.1 slot will be Gen 4 as C: drive. That leaves only 3 Gen 4 slots for my 4 drives. Not what I am looking for.
Here is what I need help with.

Would installing 2 of the drives on two individual dual-slot PCIe X16 cards in the first and second available slots (PCIe X16, NO GPU!) be faster than just one PCIe card and then two other drives in Gen 4 M.2 slots on the MB?

Comment: Just to let you know, Super User, isn’t a forum. PCIe M.2 slots typically share bandwidth with PCIe slots. Sounds like you need a different motherboard. Questions seeking hardware recommendations are out of scope

Comment: My apologies! I am not asking for hardware recommendations, I am just asking what will give me the faster read/write speeds. M.2 drives in MB slots or on a PCIe expansion card .

Comment: You are asking if splitting the bandwidth of a PCIe slot by half will be faster than PCIe M.2 slots which share bandwidth with that same slot.  You're asking if two Granny Smith Apples will taste differently.

Comment: The two options you present, are essentially identical options, since they share the same limited PCIe lanes.

Comment: I have two PCIe X16 slots, both are from the CPU.
The specs of my MB say "support for PCIe x16/ x0, x8/ x8"
Does this indicate that both slots will support a PCIe expansion card with 2 M.2  MVME cards?